# Matlab multiple minimum values

Tags: matlab

I am writing a program in MATLAB, in which i generate a 1-D array(14 elements).. 
The elements of an array can take 5 distinct values...
I want to find out what is the minimum of the array.. and ALSO if there is a unique minimum or if there are more than one minimum...

What is the most efficient way to do this.. for finding the minimum i can use the min function in MATLAB.. how to find if there are multiple instances of that minimum..
Note, i want to iterate this process a Huge no. of times(~10000) and tabulate the number of times each case occurs..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single 1D array, the two values can be found like this:

```
minValue = min(myArray);
numberOfMinValues = sum(myArray==minValue);
```

If your 1D arrays are always of the same length (and you have enough RAM), you can catenate them into a single large array, after which you only apply the functions once to save time:

```
%# assuming each 1D array is a column vector (N-by-1)
%# minValues is 1-by-M, i.e. the minimum of each of the M 1D arrays
minValues = min(myLargeArray,[],1); 
%# numberOfMinValues is, again, 1-by-M
numberOfMinValues = sum(bsxfun(@eq,myLargeArray,minValues),1);
```

Comment: +1. Also `nnz` can be used instead of `sum` - I am not sure it is faster, but it is clearer to the one who reads the code.

Comment: @Andrey: `sum` is faster than `nnz`, sadly, but you're right, `nnz` is clearer.